# DataItem in delete_command event

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I've a radgrid with delete_command event

```
protected void PointsAccountDefinitionGrid_DeleteCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
    string giftID = item["giftId"].Text;
}
```

but giftID returns " " (empty string )

any help ??

Comment: Is "giftId" columnUniqueName and it is BoundColumn?

Comment: Please check the below code snippet and let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

ASPX

```
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="MyName" HeaderText="Name">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void RadGrid1_DeleteCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
    string strID = item.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString(); //Using DataKey
    string strName1 = item["MyName"].Text; // Using BoundColumn UniqueName
    string strName2 = (item.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox).Text; // Using TemplateColumn Control
}
```